# Is there any reason to use (window.)top to reference to the current window with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, integration

I am currently trying to display a third-party website in an iFrame on an internal website. They are both located on the same second-level domain.

The third-party website uses some JavaScript script which use top and window.top to reference to the current window.

Could there be any reason for this except to prevent that the scripts work in an frame?

The third-party actually said they would support the displaying of the website in an iframe.

Could there be any other JavaScript related problems when viewing a website in an iFrame besides a reference with top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other reason for using top than to bother sites that are framing them.

Perhaps it is legacy code that had the actual code in the frameset html.

Other issues with iframes could be navigation using back and forward buttons and access denied when using a window.xxx statement